# Azure VM Restore in Parallel

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

When I try to run Parallel VM restore in PowerShell. I receive the following error message. We have functions for restoring VM, but the Parallel one does not work. Could someone please assist me with this?

```
# Function to run the restore process for VMs in parallel using PowerShell runspaces
    function Restore-VMsInParallel {
param (
\[array\]$VMsInfo
)

$runspacePool = \[RunspaceFactory\]::CreateRunspacePool(1, \[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace\]::DefaultRunspace)
$runspacePool.Open()

$jobs = @()

foreach ($vmInfo in $VMsInfo) {
$job = \[PowerShell\]::Create().AddScript({
param ($info)
Restore-VMAndSnapshots -SubscriptionId $info.SubscriptionId -ResourceGroupName $info.ResourceGroupName -VMName $info.VMName
}).AddArgument($vmInfo)

$job.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
$jobs += $job
}

$results = $jobs | ForEach-Object { $_.BeginInvoke() }
$jobs | ForEach-Object { $_.EndInvoke($\_) }

$runspacePool.Close()
$runspacePool.Dispose()
}

# Read VM details with snapshot information from the CSV file

$csvFilePath = "C:\\CSV\\file.csv"
$vms = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

# Create an array to store VM information

$vmInfoArray = @()

# Convert CSV data to VM information array

foreach ($vm in $vms) {
$vmInfo = @{
ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
VMName = $vm.VMName
SubscriptionId = $vm.SubscriptionId
}
$vmInfoArray += New-Object PSObject -Property $vmInfo
}

# Restore all VMs in parallel

Restore-VMsInParallel -VMsInfo $vmInfoArray`
```

Comment: What is the error message and the line it originates from?

Comment: If your open to installing PowerShell 7, the Foreach parallel command could probably do this, and it would look alot cleaner/simpler.